# How do I import a module one level above and use the most recent definitions?

Tags: python

**tests.py**

```
import unittest
import sys
import os
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))
import my_module.ext

print sys.path
print dir(my_module.ext)
```

But `dir` gives me the old functions. A month ago I `easy_install` an older version, and when I run `python tests.py` I get all the old functions instead.

I need the new definitions which are currently living in `my_module.ext`

```
../
  - my_module/
      - __init__.py
      - ext.py
      - core.py
      - lib.py
  - tests
      - tests.py
```

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks. The reason of not installing it is because it's a good practice to run tests before deploying the library.

FYI, they are not classes. `my_module` can be built into an egg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sys.path.insert(0, /path/to/module) rather than sys.path.append

Comment: Ahh. Thanks. That's really simple. I guess the previous statement overshadowed the new definitions. Thanks.